# Limit a ray to not go beyond a plane

Tags: roblox

As you can see from the image

[image: 1]

I want the mouse hit to not go beyond the origin’s position. If anyone knows about this, I’d like to know.

My first idea was subtract the origin to mouse hit's position and get their magnitude then subtract the mouse hit with mouse hit's look vector(unit vector) multiplied by the magnitude, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, it's a little unclear what defines the plane that is your limit?  I'm going to assume that it is the plane defined by the face of a box, and the normal vector to that face.

You know the camera position, and the direction of your ray, so once you define your plane, you should be able to calculate the intersection of that plane with your ray.

See [Ray-plane intersection](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-plane-and-ray-disk-intersection) by Scratchapixel. They have done an excellent job breaking down the equations that make this work. (Note, for this code I have renamed the `l` variables to `r`, as the variable `l0` was somewhat easy to mistake for the constant `10`)

In a LocalScript, try this...

```lua
local WorldWorkspace = game:GetService("Workspace")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local part = WorldWorkspace.Part
local camera = WorldWorkspace.CurrentCamera
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

--[[
GIVEN THE EQUATIONS...

(p - p0) ⋅ n = 0
where...
 - p is the intersection point (Vector3)
 - p0 is the origin of the plane (Vector3)
 - n is the plane perpendicular to the origin point (Vector3)

(r0 + r * t) = p
where...
 - r0 is the origin of the ray (Vector3)
 - r is the ray direction (Vector3, normalized)
 - t is the length of the ray (Vector3)
 - p is the intersection point (Vector3)

THEREFORE...
r * t ⋅ n + (r0 - p0) ⋅ n = 0

AND SOLVING FOR t WE GET...
t = ((p0 - r0) ⋅ n) / (r ⋅ n))
]]

local function calculateIntersection(n : Vector3, p0 : Vector3, r : Vector3, r0 : Vector3) : (boolean, Vector3?)
    -- returns false if the ray defined by r0 and r will never intersect with the plane defined by p0 and n
    local denominator : Vector3 = n:Dot(r)
    if denominator > 0 then
        local p010 : Vector3 = p0 - r0
        local t : Vector3 = p010:Dot(n) / denominator
        local doesIntersect : boolean = t >= 0
        local p : Vector3? = if doesIntersect then (r0 + (r * t)) else nil
        return doesIntersect, p
    end

    return false, nil
end

local function getOrigin() : Vector3
    -- calculate the origin of the intersection plane by simply using the rough bounding box.
    local cubeCenter = part.CFrame.Position
    local cubeSize = part.Size

    -- return the back face of the cube for testing
    return cubeCenter + Vector3.new(0, 0, cubeSize.Z * 0.5)
end

local function getPlane() : Vector3
    local right = part.CFrame.RightVector
    local up = part.CFrame.UpVector
    local normalPlane = right:Cross(up).Unit

    -- multiply by -1 to invert the outward direction of plane
    return -1 * normalPlane
end

local function onClick()
    -- NOTE - tweak the values of p0 and n to get the plane right
    local p0 = getOrigin()
    local n = getPlane()
    local r = mouse.Origin.LookVector
    local r0 = mouse.Origin.Position

    local success, result = calculateIntersection(n, p0, r, r0)
    if success then
        -- draw a ball where the point intersects with the plane
        -- NOTE - this will only draw on the local client, not the server
        local ball = Instance.new("Part")
        ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        ball.Size = Vector3.new(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        ball.Position = result
        ball.Anchored = true
        ball.CanCollide = false
        ball.Color = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
        ball.Parent = WorldWorkspace
    end
end

-- listen for when the player clicks
mouse.Button1Down:Connect(onClick)
```

In my testing, I was able to lock collisions to the defined plane, but I needed to mess around with the `getOrigin` and `getPlane` functions to properly define where I wanted the plane to be.

[image: A number of small red dots hover in space near a cube face. They are all aligned to a single plane.]